# How to throw an error from a service into a controller ? NestJS

Tags: rest, http, nestjs

I have a NestJs controller that calls a handleRequests function of a service.
In this function, I call another function: addAFriend.
So this function, I can throw an error.

So my question is the following:
How to catch this error in my controller?

I tried to handle it with a try catch around the call of the first addAFriend function.
And catch error and then with conditions on if instance of ...

But when I try to call my endpoint on the controller (and trying to simulate throwing the error), I get a 200 status that everything is ok, and then the error is thrown, but in the console -> and the application stops.

What can I do?

And moreover, is it a good way to call a function that directly calls another function in my controller?

Here is the controller:

```
@Put()
  async handleFriendRequest(
    @Res() response: any,
    @Body() handleFriendRequestDto: HandleFriendRequestDto,
  ) {
    try {
      const friendRequestToHandle =
        await this.friendRequestService.handleFriendRequest(
          handleFriendRequestDto,
        );
      return response.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
        message: 'Friend Request has been successfully handled',
        friendRequestToHandle,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof SenderNotFoundException) {
        throw new HttpException(
          {
            status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
            code: 'USER_SENDER_NOT_FOUND',
            error: 'User sender not found',
            message: 'We could not found the user sender with id ${id}',
          },
          HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
          {
            cause: error,
          },
        );
      } else if (error instanceof FriendRequestNotFoundException) {
        throw new HttpException(
          {
            status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
            code: 'FRIEND_REQUEST_NOT_FOUND',
            error: 'Friend Request not found',
            message: 'We could not found the friend request with id ${id}',
          },
          HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
          {
            cause: error,
          },
        );
      } else if (error instanceof ReceiverNotFoundException) {
        throw new HttpException(
          {
            status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
            code: 'USER_RECEIVER_NOT_FOUND',
            error: 'User receiver not found',
            message: 'We could not found the user receiver with id ${id}',
          },
          HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
          {
            cause: error,
          },
        );
      } else if (error instanceof UserAlreadyFriendException) {
        throw new HttpException(
          {
            status: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            code: 'USER_ALREADY_FRIEND',
            error: 'User receiver is already a friend',
            message: 'User receiver is already a friend',
          },
          HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
          {
            cause: error,
          },
        );
      } else {
        return response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
          message: 'We could not add the user',
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to see the code of the function ```handleFriendRequest``` ?
To see how the error is thrown.